# How many ways to perform any action in android device by just one button click from website or admin panel (Server )?

Tags: android, web-services, push-notification

Good morning guys,

Can anyone please describe and elaborate that how many ways to perform any action like

- Start service
- ON GPS etc...

in Android device based on just one button click from admin panel which we have created.

I know some of the solution like

-> When application start then one service continuously running and check the status of button click from database through webservices.

but that is not better solution because lots of disadvantage like battery dranage...etc...

-> When any superadmin just click button from admin panel at that time with the help of push notification we can notify to android device to perform action.

but google can not give guaranty to everytime reach push notification on device.

Can any one please help me to give suggestions except above and elaborate it. ?

Answer (score 1):

application pulls status from server continuously is the best way for situations. Consider android device is a HTTP client, HTTP commutation always start by client request.

Comment: Hi Jinang, Thank you for your quick response. If we use this mechanism then It might be possible to dranage battery etc...And also If we have lots of features like GPS On,service start by particular time and lots of filtered option... SO It is little bit complex...Can't we find another option ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/), it is easy to use library from google for android, ios and chrome. By using this your app can receive any message sent by the your server(through GCM service) very efficiently without any battery drain and very less code. GCM handles various scenarios for you like load handling, network connectivity, authorization etc.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Some times GCM push notifications are not coming. Also google do not give guarantee for push notification everytime reach. How to handle this situation ?

Comment: Its going to be a trade off between performance, maintanance and efficiency. But the error rate in GCM is very low, it handles a lot negative scenarios like poor network, battery drain etc. So if it was upto me i'd choose GCM

Comment: Thank you rajesh for your kindly response..:)